# React Javascript Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

if I have a local constant like

```
result = [{id: 1, a:"1", b:"2"},{id:2, a:"3", b:"4"}]
```

my map function in react js works fine.

If I make a request to my database I get the same back, but as a string. But then the map function fails. I tried some Parse Function but didn't get it to work.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
  var db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db');

  db.serialize(function() {
    db.all(`SELECT * from List WHERE a LIKE '%${search}%' OR b LIKE '%${search}%'`,function(err,rows){
      console.log(rows)
      console.log('---------------------')
      console.log(' ')
      if (err) {
        log(err)
        res.status(400).send(err)
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(rows)
      }
    });
  });
  db.close();
```

Any idea?

Best regards

Comment: Your question lacks important details. How did you retrieve data from the database? Can you show some samples of the outcome from the database? Also include how you are manipulating the data, in particular the map operation.

Comment: @E_net4:

The map functions works with the local array, but not with database output.

  var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
  var db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db');

  db.serialize(function() {
    db.all(`SELECT * from List WHERE a LIKE '%${search}%' OR b LIKE '%${search}%'`,function(err,rows){
      console.log(rows)
      console.log('---------------------')
      console.log(' ')
      if (err) {
        log(err)
        res.status(400).send(err)
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(rows)
      }
    });
  });
  db.close();

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to get, and the errors that you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse that object with `JSON.parse(string)` first.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i am wondering why it didn't worked before (i tried JSON.parse()). Maybe I did the parsing in the nodeJS backend and not in the frontend.